# How to read binary array directly from the stream?

Tags: c#, arrays

Here by "directly" I mean without temporary `byte[]` array.

The problem is, for example I have array of `ints` or `doubles` on the disk, so currently I create two arrays -- `byte` array and `int` array (in case of `ints`). The former is just for reading, the latter is the actual output.

Since `Stream` can read only to `byte` array I read it to the first array, than copy all the data to the second. It works, but it really hurts me (I am not talking about performance here).

So, how to read the array without temporary array? Using C# `unsafe` context is fine for me.

*So far I tried two approaches: I looked if it is possible to create an array reusing allocated memory and second which looked more promising -- I could get pointer to the result/second array and in unsafe context I could cast it to `byte*` pointer. Considering my needs it is 100% safe and valid, however `byte*` pointer is not a `byte[]` array in C# world and I cannot find the way to cast pointer to array.*

Code:

```
void ReadStuff(Stream stream, double[] data)
{  
  var dataBytes = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(double)];
  stream.Read(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
  Buffer.BlockCopy(dataBytes, 0, data, 0, dataBytes.Length);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: No.  Use Read() method with number of bytes you need and put into a byte[].  You do not need to read the entire stream to end.  You can check the position and length of stream to make sure there is enough data in stream before reading.

Comment: @jdweng, you mean reading it in the loop, sure, but I still need temporary array for that. So it leads nowhere. Half an array is still an array (yes, I am aware, I can gain performance this way, but I would also to remove the need of temporary array).

Comment: If you have a million byte array and need to read a four byte integer, you do not read the entire stream.  Binary data you are reading a known format and know the length of each object.   Microsoft made the c# managed library very limited to prevent blue screen exceptions.

Comment: @astrowalker your question isn't clear. [Stream.Read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read?view=netcore-3.1) fills a reusable buffer with just the bytes you asked. So there's no temporary array involved. If you have *a lot* of concurrent operations and worry that even those buffers can harm performance you could use a [MemoryPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=netcore-3.1) to reuse the same buffer across streams. You certainly don't need a byte pointer. If you don't want to copy arrays, you can use `Span<byte>`

Comment: @astrowalker you should probably post your code instead of describing it

Comment: @jdweng, "If you have a million byte array and need to read a four byte integer" -- then I would ask how to read single integer out of entire file, yet I asked how to read entire array.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, putting aside "just  the bytes" could be megabytes and they have to be stored somewhere, the API for streams request byte array. So I have to create it just in sake of reading anything despite I don't need byte array at all. I am aware of `MemoryPool`, it still creates an array it just don't pressure GC that much.

Comment: Then your question is wrong.  You want your cake and have your pie too.  You are asking for performance and want to read the entire array.  Reading the entire array you use more memory and it take longer so you loose performance.

Comment: @astrowalker all languages, all runtimes, all OSs work like that. When you use a `byte*` in C, you also work like that. Someone allocated that array. And since you use the *same* buffer each time, there's no waste or extra GC involved even with a *single* stream. MemoryPool is used when you need to conserve memory across thousands of streams, eg when you have a high-traffic web service. So what's the real problem? Why look at a `byte*`? If you want to avoid copying, you use `Stream.Read(Span<byte>)`

Comment: @jdweng, I wrote that it hurts **me** (I am not CPU), but sure, I rephrased it to make it clear. I just want to get ride of extra array, that's it.

Comment: @astrowalker your code is *not* how streams are used. Instead of allocating the full size, use a *small* buffer. Otherwise you could use `ReadAllBytes()`. There's no need for `BlockCopy` in any case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I doubt it, small chunks of memory can be safely put on stack, not heap. But thank you very much for mentioning new API!

Comment: `BinaryReader` can be used to read integers and bytes from part of stream https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you caught me with `BlockCopy` -- if you use some additional buffer how do you transfer data from one array to another?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way I know of to copy data directly from a stream to a typed array. But you can process the data in chunks, limiting your memory overhead to a fixed amount. The memory will be copied twice, but this is unavoidable as far as I know.

For example:

```
            public static void ReadArrayDataChunked(BinaryReader binaryReader, Array target, Type type, int bufferSize = 4096)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        var tSize = Marshal.SizeOf(type) ;

        var remainingBytes = target.Length * tSize;
        var targetPosition = 0;
        while (remainingBytes > 0)
        {
            var toRead = Math.Min(remainingBytes, buffer.Length);
            var bytesRead = binaryReader.Read(buffer, 0, toRead);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, target, targetPosition, bytesRead);
            targetPosition += bytesRead;
            remainingBytes -= bytesRead;
        }
    }
```

Note that this only works for primitive types due to the BlockCopy, but this helps improve copy performance. You will need to read other types item by item.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it looks like I end up following this path, because I don't see a glue that connects my "outer" needs (like double array) with stream API needs (byte array).

Comment: If you have a `double[]` and want a `byte[]` or vice versa you could just do a block-Copy directly, no need for a stream to do that.

Comment: My data (doubles) are on the disk, so I need stream to read them in the first place.